# How do I iterate over two arrays in parallel with liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have 2 arrays "a_group" [a,a,a,a] and "b_group" [b,b,b] 
I'm iterating with the following loop:

```
 {% for  a in a_group and b in b_group %}
         <p> {{ a }}: {{b}} </p>  
{% endfor %}
```

expected result:
a: b 
a: b
a: b
a: No data available

what i actually get:
a: No data available 
a: No data available
a: No data available
a: No data available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need both an A element and a B element at the same time, you can always use indexes to cherry-pick them off, or nested loops. There is no concept of parallel processing that will help you otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

As per David sir's guideline, this can possible using the indexes. below might help to implement in the code.

```
{% assign a_group = 'a1,a2,a3'  | split: ',' %}

{% assign b_group = 'b1,b2,b3' | split: ',' %}

{% for a in a_group %}

    <p> {{ a }} : {{ b_group[forloop.index0] }} </p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You don't need to assign index in your example - you can just use `{{ b_group[forloop.index0] }}` (Reference: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/for-loops)